# In Sherlock: Study in Pink how does the choice of bottles work?

Tags: plot-explanation, sherlock

In [Sherlock season 1 episode 1](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1665071/) the serial killer asks Sherlock to take one of two bottles. 1 bottle is ok other is bad (poisonous). Whatever bottle Sherlock takes the serial killer takes the other one. That is same way the serial killer murdered his other victims.

But the episode doesn't say  how exactly serial killer achieved this. Before Sherlock can take one of the bottles the serial killer is murdered.

Does anybody know how the serial killer achieved this?

Comment: Has it been asked why would the victims even want to take the pill? The lady MP was certainly not taking a taxi.

Answer (score 22):

The cabbie is indeed shown to be terminally ill and wants to raise money for his family. However, this only explains why he resorts to killing people (=earn money fast). Motives of Moriarty are part of the bigger overall story arc in the Sherlock Holmes universe as Moriarty is the arch-nemesis of Sherlock.

The poison pill trick is not random. The cabbie is skilled in reading and manipulating people. He has analyzed what drives his victims and acts accordingly. He knew Sherlock would get in his cab instead of calling the police. The poison pill trick is his way of showing he has control through his skill. His victims can make the choice but as they are choosing, the cabbie manipulates them. He knows which of the bottles is poisonous and will manipulate his victims into taking the bad bottle. If they take the good one, he will convince them to change their mind. This shows of how good the cabbie is in reading people, predicting their train of thought and knowing what to say to mislead them. It takes great skill to manipulate people that know you are trying to kill them.

His confrontation with Sherlock is a battle in the understanding of human behavior. It is a match to decide who can better see through the other's act. They have layers and layers of bluff/misdirection in all the small details of their actions.

Comment: This again is a theoretical answer. Choosing from the 2 bottles is pure chance. No matter how good he is at manipulating people it is still a huge chance. What happens if victims chooses to stick to their choice and has in fact chosen the good bottle. Its very unlikely way to kill 3 victim. I just believe there had to be some trick involved that he used. He did say he would win every time he tried; so it just can't be a matter of chance.

Comment: @minusSeven You seem to underestimate the effect that his mind manipulation can have for raising his chances. It may not have worked with *Sherlock*, who may have realized that sticking to the 50% of his initial choice is better than messing with his mind plays. But the other victims maybe really thought they could beat him or were easier to manipulate. Probably not 100% for the cabbie, but definitely better than 50% and maybe sufficient for 3 easy victims. If you really expected a *"non-theoretical"* actual (physical) trick, then no, there is none.

Comment: @minusSeven *"He did say he would win every time he tried"* - And you believe him to say the ultimate 100% thruth, especially considering the mind manipulation context? Congratulations for taking the wrong pill. ;)

Comment: @ChristianRau The fact is no matter how good he is at mind manipulation it is still a matter of chance. There is no proof to show that he manipulated his victims into choosing the wrong bottle. That is hypothetical. Even more so when Sherlock is about to leave he asks Sherlock to say what he would have chosen just to know if he was wrong. That means Sherlock had figured out the trick involved. Maybe the future shows clear this up as to what was the right answer.

Comment: @minusSeven: It is clearly shown in the episode that the cabbie is skilled at predicting human behavior. I think it is highly unlikely that the writers would portray him as being 'Sherlock using his powers for evil' and would then use a cheap trick to explain his success. It's also unlikely that if his victims would choose the correct bottle, he would simply take the poison. If you're really looking for a trick : he promises to take whichever bottle is left but just shoots his victims when he would lose.

Comment: or maybe both bottles are poisonous and he has an antidote. or maybe he would force feed his victims the poison when he loses. There is nothing forcing him to honour his "I take what's left". However, without an actual scene from one of the murders, all answers are speculative. I just believe my posted answer is best in line with the whole episode and the characters portrayal.

Comment: @Origin Well none of his victims were shot. If you had a choice between poison and being shot would really choose poison? Yes your answer is speculative. One can try reading the actual novel to find out what had happened. Or maybe an answer may come out in future episode you never know.

Comment: @minusSeven There won't likely be an answer in a future episode, neither does the novel give one, since they diverge too much in this regard. All in all eveything is speculative, but in the end I agree with *Origin* that his answer is actually based on *what is told in the movie's story* and you cannot get more unspeculative than this. Of course there is no ultimate proof in the show, since none of the murders is shown, but it is clearly depicted this way. It is completely your decision if you believe the movie's story or not, but if you don't, be prepared for speculative answers.

Comment: I agree with Origin's answer that the "_trick_" was the cabbie's ability to manipulate people. For normal people there is only the possibility of a bluff or the truth, whereas, the cabbie was so adept in cold-reading and psychological manipulation that he could successfully pull not only a bluff, but a double or triple bluff! So at the end, you are going to consume the pill which the cabbie **wants** you to consume.

Comment: @Origin: to manipulate his victims, the cab driver has to know in which bottle is the poison. Is there any evidence of this in the TV show? 

Also, the taxi driver, though very smart, is not an "evil Sherlock". That's Moriarty's function.

Comment: @Taladris: True and true, he should have to know that and 'evil Sherlock' was just shorthand to make my point. The producers did (in my opinion) portray him as someone using deductive reasoning to manipulate and kill people. I should have to review the episode to know if he knew which of the bottles was poison. However, I stand by my answer and other arguments above

Answer (score 20):

The killer was terminally ill with a brain aneurism and could die at any moment.  He was using the 'scheme' to raise money.  He was earning money from Moriarty, who was essentially sponsoring the cabbie to murder people in this manner. Moriarty's motive is unclear, perhaps just to cause chaos, but more likely to get his name in front of Sherlock.

Essentially the cabbie had nothing to lose - so it was purely random which pill was poison.  On each occasion he had a 50% chance of winning.  As the only repeat player, the odds are that he would die within a few rounds, but a fairly good chance he would kill one or two in the process - raising money for his family.  He viewed himself as being expendable, likely to die at any moment anyway - an intelligent man, he viewed it as a risk worth taking.

[Alternative (not very serious theory): Perhaps he has built up an immunity to [Iocaine powder](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9s0UURBihH8)?]

Comment: Hmmm. That's an interesting explanation.

Comment: the guy killed 3 people before Sherlock. That makes the chances about 12%. And he did say he would win every time he tried. There had to be some trick involved.

Comment: @minusSeven: I agree 12% is small odds, but far from being impossible. However each event is a separate 'roll of the dice'.  Once he survive he might as well do it again - he has a 50% chance of wining again.  I think the 'win every time' could be part of the 'script' he's been given from Moriarty to entice Sherlock.

Comment: And I always thought he was some kind of poker genius able to read other peoples' minds. But maybe this whole *"I can play everybody's mind to always win the correct bottle"*-show was really just to distract *Sherlock*.

Comment: He is also able to apply some manipulation should the wrong bottle be chosen by the victim.  This must skew the odds a little (but not much) in his favor.

Comment: My first thought was that of an Iocaine powder so +10 to you.

Answer (score 13):

Both pills have poison. You see but you do not observe!

The cabbie opens the bottle and holds the pill in his *left* hand. He talks and distracts Holmes. Just before he is shot you see him with a pill in his *right* hand. He had a second, non-poison pill, all the time. He did this with all the victims. None had a chance, the game was rigged.

At time 1:19:36 the pill is in his left hand.

[image: At 1:19:36 the pill is in his left hand]

At time 1:19:54 the pill is in his right hand.

[image: At time 1:19:54 the pill is in his right hand]

Comment: If you can add some evidence like screenshots and such this would be a much more complete answer.  Right now it seems more like a rambling opinion without proper structure.

Comment: Interesting answer. Just watched this and the pill does actually switch hands between cuts but it appears more likely to me to be a simple filming/editing continuity error. I didn't see any frame with both hands visible at once.

Comment: While theres no evidence, this seems like the most reasonable answer that is not "it's purely up to chance"

Comment: Correct! Perhaps this is the reason why cabbie remained silent even during his last moments of life when Holmes asked him which pill was poisonous.

Answer (score 12):

There's another explanation although without evidence of course.

Neither of the pills were poisonous. The poison was in a glass of water he would offer the victims to wash it down with. He'd dry swallow the pill. In my opinion it's one of the better answers.

However everything is entirely speculation so it could easily be wrong.

Comment: No. no. He spent the last 3 years building up an immunity to Iocaine Powder...or was that a different movie :)

Answer (score 10):

Could be the pills are his meds. If he takes them it does nothing (they're prescribed for a reason), but when someone else takes them they die.

Comment: That is a surprisingly good answer.

Comment: Interesting angle. Seems more probable to find drug where you can simply take anti dote beforehand.

Answer (score 3):

I heard my favorite theory on tumblr and expanded on it. 
Neither pill was poison, and the water he gave them was. He swallowed his dry. This explanation has no evidence in the episode to support it, but it still fits the events and I like it a lot.

One problem that I noticed is that there is no water in the final scene where they are both about to take the pills. One way to explain this is that the cabbie's sponsor Moriarty (who has been described as a 'fan' of Sherlock) did not want Sherlock dead. If neither of them used poison water then neither one would die. Presumably, the cabbie would fake his own death, let Sherlock think he had chosen right, and then who knows?

Comment: I was with you right up until I read "fake your own death" this is Sherlock we're talking about!

Answer (score 1):

This is covered in the episode, Holmes mentions it to the cabbie and the cabbie replies something like:

> Four games and four wins, that's not random

If you want an excellent, explained example of this in action - watch The Princess Bride:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U_eZmEiyTo0

The man in black's intelligence test. He provides two vials, one of which is poisoned.

Vizzini explains his chain of thought thus expressing how he feels that the placement of the poisons is not random but is a psychological trick. In the same way the taxi driver feels that there is psychology in the way he plays his 'game' and that it is not random - whether either if them are right or wrong is not the point, the point is that they feel there is more to it than random chance

Note: the twist in the Princess Bride's version about immunities is not relevant to the Holmes's version.  I only included this as it explained the chain of thought as to which glass should be drunk from.

Comment: Can't really watch at work but why does the Princess Bride explain this situation?

Comment: The man in black's intelligence test.  He provides two vials, one of which is poisoned.  The Sicilian talks through his reasoning as to whether he should take the vial closest or furthest depending on where he thinks the Man in Black would put it.

Comment: Most likely cause the answer is shorter than others and maybe not fully read through.  I will say this though, if you include that summary of the video with your answer that will help your answer :D

Comment: Hmmm, good point.

Comment: the answer is that the poison is in both the glasses but the guy questioning is immune to the poison .

Comment: True but that is not so relevant to the Holmes episode

Comment: @minusSeven: that's speculative, there is nothing in the episode that hints at any immunity, they say nothing about the cabbie being immune

Comment: @Origin yes that is but the link to the princess bride where the same thing is shown explains it

Comment: In the Princess Bride the Man in Black is immune to the poison but that is not relevant to the Holmes episode - I only included it because of the Sicilians's explanation of which drink he should take

Comment: Sorry, but since this answer successfully (even if not intentionally) lead the OP onto a completely wrong track, I have no choice than downvote it.

Comment: Apology accepted

Comment: Vizzini's 'logic' is not meant to be taken seriously (e.g. _"the poison comes from Australia, and Australia is entirely people with criminals, ergo...)_, so I'm not sure how this tongue-in-cheek scene from _The Princess Bride_ is supposed to explain what happens in 'Sherlock Holmes'.

Comment: Vizzini explains his chain of thought thus expressing how he feels that the placement of the poisons is not random but is a psychological trick. In the same way the taxi driver feels that there is psychology in the way he plays his 'game' and that it is not random - whether either if them are right or wrong is not the point, the point is that they feel there is more to it than random chance.

Comment: Answer updated as requested