# The pills in "A Study in Pink"

Tags: sherlock

In the *Sherlock* episode "A Study in Pink", was the taxi driver bluffing when he asserted that there were two kinds of pills, those that kill and those that are harmless? I am not sure.

Comment: I hope you don't mind, but I've reworded the question to be less opinion-based. "Do you think he was bluffing?" isn't a suitable question for the site, but "Is he bluffing?" should be.

Comment: Related question asking how the taxi driver's scheme worked ... https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/10432/in-sherlock-study-in-pink-how-does-the-choice-of-bottles-work